# Repa arrays indexed by a bounded data type?

Tags: arrays, haskell, repa

I want to achieve something similar to the bounded arrays in the standard array package but using repa arrays.

What is the nice and clean way to achieve this?

This is what I tried, but there must be a better way than wrapping everything in custom functions that check for bounds:

```
import  Data.Array.Repa

data C = A | F | L deriving (Eq,Enum,Ord,Bounded,Show)

data Ballot c = Ballot {
    vote::Array U (Z :. Int) Int
    } deriving Show

mkBallot::(Eq c ,Enum c,Ord c, Bounded c, Show c) => c -> Ballot c
mkBallot c = Ballot $ fromListUnboxed (Z :. max) (genSc c)
where
    max = (fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` c)) + 1

genSc::(Eq c,Enum c,Ord c,Bounded c,Show c) => c -> [Int]
genSc c = [ f x | x <- enumFrom (minBound `asTypeOf` c) , let f v = if x == c then 1 else 0]

showScore c b = index (vote b) (Z :. ((fromEnum c)))
```

Also I have tried to derive a Shape instance for (sh :. C) but to no avail, I can't really get my head around on how to implement some of the interfaces declared in the Shape class for my data type. I am writing the question with the hope that someone else has a way, but if not, I shall try again. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a shape instance for a wrapper around your bounded enum.  I'm not sure this is the best way, but it sort of does what you want, I think.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}

import Data.Array.Repa
```

Here we make a shape instance over bounded things.  We need an end-of-index for "full" arrays.

```
data Idx a = Idx a | EOI
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

fromIdx :: forall a . (Bounded a, Enum a) => Idx a -> Int
fromIdx EOI = fromEnum (maxBound :: a) - fromEnum (minBound :: a) + 1
fromIdx (Idx x) = fromEnum x - fromEnum (minBound :: a)

toIdx ::  forall a . (Bounded a, Enum a) => Int -> Idx a
toIdx i | i < 0 = error "negative index"
toIdx i = case compare i range of
  LT -> Idx $ toEnum (i + fromEnum (minBound :: a))
  EQ -> EOI
  GT -> error "out of range"
  where
    range = fromEnum (maxBound :: a) - fromEnum (minBound :: a) + 1

instance (Bounded a, Enum a, Ord a) => Shape (Idx a) where
  rank _ = 1
  zeroDim = Idx minBound
  unitDim = Idx $ succ minBound
  intersectDim EOI n = n
  intersectDim n EOI = n
  intersectDim (Idx n1) (Idx n2) = Idx $ min n1 n2
  addDim = error "undefined"
  size = fromIdx
  sizeIsValid _ = True
  toIndex _ n = fromIdx n
  fromIndex _ i = toIdx i
  inShapeRange _ _ EOI = error "bad index"
  inShapeRange n1 n2 n = n >= n1 && n <= n2
  listOfShape n = [fromIdx n]
  shapeOfList [i] = toIdx i
  shapeOfList _ = error "unsupported shape"
  deepSeq (Idx n) x = n `seq` x
  deepSeq _ x = x
```

With that, the ballot part is easy and clean:

```
data C = A | F | L deriving (Eq, Enum, Ord, Bounded, Show)

data Ballot c = Ballot { vote :: Array U (Idx c) Int
                       } deriving Show

mkBallot :: (Eq c, Enum c, Ord c, Bounded c, Show c) => c -> Ballot c
mkBallot c = Ballot $ fromListUnboxed EOI vec
  where
    vec = map (fromEnum . (== c)) [minBound .. maxBound]
```